Angular Material 18: Chip text with overflow
I would like the text inside my chips to display ... when it is too long.
Currently and by default, I have this
chip without overflow ellipsis
But I want it to look like this :
chip with overflow ellipsis
I tried this in my component level
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-chip-set-stacked .mdc-evolution-chip-set__chips {
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    :host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__cell--primary,
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary,
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-standard-chip .mat-mdc-chip-action-label {
      overflow: hidden;
    }


but this only works for angular 16, but not for angular 17/18.

Solved: wrap the text inside a block like div
<mat-chip-option>
  <div class="container">
    {{ label }}
  </div>
  <button>
    <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-chip-option>

and add the following css
mat-chip-option .container {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


Instead of writing the css in component using ::ng-deep as it is being deprecated, its better to use in styles.css
I have tried for this example
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples#chips-autocomplete
Below is the css for the mat-chip-row , apply it in the styles.css
//properties need to be applied in styles.css
.mat-mdc-chip.mdc-evolution-chip--with-trailing-action .mat-mdc-chip-action-label {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mdc-evolution-chip__action.mat-mdc-chip-action.mdc-evolution-chip__cell.mdc-evolution-chip__cell--primary.mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

The above is working for the angular 18 .
Below is the working example for the text inside the chips to display ... when it is too long.
output of the above example 

The problem with that is that it overrides it for the whole project, instead of just for the one time I need.
